# What is the etymology of "business end"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

What is the origin of the phrase "business end"?

Answer (score 5):

According to their entry last updated in 2012:

> [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/business-end_n?tab=factsheet#11688021)'s earliest evidence for business end is from 1828, in Daily National Intelligencer (Washington).

This isn't however the usual modern meaning but rather "The part of a day, or aspect or facet of an activity, that relates to business."

The text of that 1828 quote is:

> The practical result..was to take off an hour from the business end of the day, and add it to the…

More than a decade later they attest some other meanings including "The end of a city, road, etc., that is given over chiefly to business premises; a main or important business district" (1836) and what might be the most common meaning now "The operative or functional end or part of something, esp. a tool or weapon" (1840).

There's also "An aim or goal that relates to business. Frequently in plural" from 1854.

Almost fifty years later, in 1890, we see the other common meaning "In extended use: the important, essential, or decisive part of an operation, process, period of time, etc." I think that corresponds to the following 1890 quote from the Daily Inter Ocean (Chicago):

> After disposing of the resolutions, which were the ‘business end’ of the report…

Answer (score 4):

There is no special etymology as such. Business could stand for **activity** or **commercial operation**. So business end means the end (could be the tip, as in the *business end of the fork*) which performs or involves the maximum activity or work.

In a long tournament like the World Cup, the knock-out phase could be called **business end**, because it is the period of intense activity (and also is commercially most popular) involving the best teams.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really have an origin as such. It is just *business* + *end*, much the same as pointed end or any other end.

It has been recorded in use since around the first half of the 19th century, at that time usually in reference to actual businesses - "the business end of the street".